# Disappearing parts when parenting and rigging

Tags: modeling, animation, rigging

first I am new to the asking questions here just cause I can't find what I am looking for.

I created a door with a glass panel and added a door handle and latch pin, as well as hinges. Everything works good and smooth, but with the parenting and such 2 items are completely not visible, they are there in the content listing but they don't show in the image.

So I am lost I looked and looked at the detail tried changing a few things and nothing changed. I have a save file, and I don`t see any way of sharing this to show the issue.

May someone tell me what I am doing wrong.

[image]

Comment: If you want it, post your file using this link: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Welcome to Blender Stack Exchange! At what point did the objects disappear? If it was when you parented them, what type of parenting did you use?